# The reason why he chooses past tense

Tags: word-usage, tense

In a movie, there is an expression which I can not understand. The situation is like the following.

> There are two men, A and B, driving in a car and calling a third person over a mobile's speakerphone.
>
> A: I don't want to listen to him (the third person) anymore.
>
> (A throws the mobile phone out though a window)
>
> B: That was mine.

I don't understand why B says "That was mine."

This sentence has past tense. Even though A throws the phone out, does the phone still belong to B?

So it is natural that B should express his opinion by using present tense, isn't it?

Comment: You are inconsistent. Whose phone is it? Who throws it out the window?

Comment: B owned the phone

Comment: Then why do you ask "Does the phone still belong to A?"

Comment: it might difference between English and mother-tongue. people from my country say usually that is mine!! they choose present tense.

Comment: The situation, and the dialogue are virtually meaningless.  I've voted to close as I can't understand what you are asking here.

Comment: @JamesK I've improved the question. Do you understand it now?

Comment: @gotube I made a few more small edits, but it's still confusing. For example, the blockquote says that "A throws the mobile phone out", but OP writes that "B throws the phone out". Uggh.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I fixed that part too, based on the OP's comment above. Anyway, I hope we all understand the story now

Answer (score 3):

The phone *no longer* belongs to B (or anyone else), whether because it was destroyed when it hit the ground or simply because it is now lost and they are driving away from it.

The present tense *could* be used with an elision:

> Hey, that's mine!

But the past tense is more natural in this situation:

> Hey, that was mine!

Not full present tense, as that would sound a little stilted:

> (x) Hey, that is mine!

Comment: Additionally I'd say the use of past tense reflects that the action that's referred to (the throw) is in the past. Saying something _was_ yours doesn't rule out that it still _is_ yours, but the "point of interest" is in the past, so to speak.

Comment: I think you're both right. It could mean B means the phone is no longer his, or it could mean he's referring to the incident in the past, which is very common. For instance, I intend to hand someone their phone, but I hand them mine instead. I could say, "*Sorry, that **was** my phone. Here's yours.*" The phone was and still is mine, and this is totally natural English